# Image disappears if url is deleted

Tags: jquery, html, default

Below is my jQuery for a meme generator I'm learning to build. Basically whenever a user enters a URL and deletes it, the original default image disappears and I'm struggling with how to get the image to return to its default state if the user removes their input.

```
var main = function() {

  $('#top-text').keyup(function() {
    var top = $(this).val();
    $('.top-caption').text(top);
});
  $('#bottom-text').keyup(function() {
    var bottom = $(this).val();
    $('.bottom-caption').text(bottom)
});
  $('#image-url').keyup(function() {
    var image = $(this).val();
    $('div.meme > img').attr('src',image);
 });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

This specific code here is where I can't figure out how to get the default image to reload if a user deletes their URL.

```
$('#image-url').keyup(function() {
    var image = $(this).val();
    $('div.meme > img').attr('src',image);
```

Here is the corresponding HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="pikachulollipop.gif">
    <h1>Cal's Meme Generator</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="meme thumbnail">
          <img src="pancham.png">
          <h1 class="top-caption">U say something?</h1>
          <h1 class="bottom-caption">Deal with it</h1>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="tool">
          <h2>Create a meme</h2>
          <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Image URL</label>
              <input id="image-url" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Top text</label>
              <input id="top-text" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Bottom text</label>
              <input id="bottom-text" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image starts with a default of `pancham.png` - I assume you want that reset:

```
$('#image-url').keyup(function() {
    var image = $(this).val() || "pancham.png";
    $('div.meme > img').attr('src',image);
});
```

Comment: That fixed it!!! I made this way too hard when the answer was really simple. Thank you!!